# Need Advice on How to Pass Entire JTable from one panel to another panel form

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two panel forms; one with JTable with populated data.  I would like to have the entire table passed to another table in another panel form.  I believe I need to overload the constructor in the second panel form with the DefaultTableModel, but I want to ensure I have the correct code in the first panel to pass that data via a button called "report".  Any ideas would be much appreciated in advance.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code, and then write specifically what it won't do and what you want it to do?

Comment: I have this in original form: public JTable getTableData(){
        return this.jTable_caseInfo;
    }

Comment: I also have this in original form:   private void jButton_reportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable_caseInfo.getModel();
    }

Comment: I have this in new form with blank table:   public CaseNewTable(DefaultTableModel model){
        
    }

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how to get the "entire" contents of the table to fill in the new form's blank table.  I understand if it was a value of getText for a textbox, but what about entire table contents?